# Is there a way do open a navigation drawer in front of a dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have an small app that uses a Navigation Drawer as menu. This looks. My problem is that the drawer should also be available when there are some modal dialog fragments are opened.

I managed to recognize the swipe gestures correctly using the GestureDetector and forward the result to the main activity. That calls the

```
    drawerLayout.openDrawer
```

method. Works fine but the drawer appears in the background of the dialog.

Is there an easy way to bring the drawer to front?

- do I have to create an own fragment for the navigation drawer and handle it by myself?
- if so, do you know any code examples how this can be easily archived
- do I have to somehow specify drawer for the dialog fragment (how)?

All suggestions/hints are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, dialogs are used to require user action/input before continuing, so why would you want to do bypass this normal behavior?

Comment: It's not my decision. The app is ported from a WinME device and precondition was that it looks similar. Dialogs are used for flow control but there are menu items that could always be selected to perform additional actions that are independent of the current state of the main view.
I'm not doing this because I want to do it that way, it is because I have it to do like that.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm ended up with is following:

- I'm using an own dialog interface, basically providing the standard methods of the dialog (show/dismiss/...).
- There is one implementation extending a real dialog (to be used in cases where no menu is necessary)
- Another one is extending a fragment (NO DialogFragment)
- My own dialog style fragment creates a semi-transparent layout covering the whole screen consuming the touch events. Within that there is a relative layout holding the view / content of the dialog (what is set by setContentView). That layout uses a background drawable that defines the look of an dialog.
- The show/dismiss methods will add/remove it from fragment manager.

So it is a normal fragment containing a view representing a dialog. I also check several attributes (location, flags that can be set to a dialog) and try to apply them to the displayed view.

I'm not completely happy with that approach and it definitely has several drawbacks but for now it fullfills my needs.